# Is it possible to stack jquery animations?

Tags: jquery

Something like "if there is one or more effects to run first, wait your time to be executed", one at a time.

```
var stack = [];
stack.push( $(obj).fadeIn() );
```

Am I being insane on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you put each one of them in a callback function?

Comment: You could use promisses

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 1):

> if there is one or more effects to run first, wait your time to be executed

What you've described is called "queueing" and jQuery's [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) method is how it's implemented.

Animations already use `.queue()` internally, so simply chain them.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('div')
    .css('position', 'relative')
    .hide()
    .slideDown()
    .slideUp()
    .fadeIn()
    .fadeOut()
    .queue(function (next) {
      $(this).show();
      next();
    }).animate({
      top: 20,
      left: 50
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  this is an example
</div>
```

Comment: And if some of the animations are displayed with mouse move events, and in more than one element?

Answer (score 0):

You could promise animations like this:

```
$('elem').promise().done({
    //call animation
});
```

or call an animation after the other one finishes like

```
$('elem').animate('opacity','1',function(){
    $(this).animate(stuff);
});
```